# menuWillOpen: and menuDidClose: not invoked for NSMenuDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[Edit] as Willeke helpfully points out it's `menuDidClose:` NOT `menuWillClose:`. My code actually had that part right. Correcting the post in case someone else finds this researching a similar problem.

I'm sure this is just a Cocoa newbie problem but I've wracked my brain on it for hours. I've read the NSMenu and NSMenuDelegate docs a few times trying to figure out what I'm missing but it looks straight forward.

I have a window controller for a preferences window with a toolbar and three views. The window controller is declared as NSMenuDelegate.

```
@interface PrefsController : NSWindowController <NSMenuDelegate, NSWindowDelegate, NSOpenSavePanelDelegate>
```

This issue is a NSPopUpButton on the first view. The menu associated with popupbutton works fine. I can modify, etc. the menu via the associated IBOutlet variable. It's bound to Shared User Defaults Controller for selected value and that works fine.

But the `menuWillOpen:` and `menuDidClose:` methods are not invoked when the menu is accessed.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    if (menu == myPopupButton.menu) {
        [self updateMenuImages:NSMakeSize(32, 32)];
    }
}


- (void)menuDidClose:(NSMenu *)menu {
    if (menu == myPopupButton.menu) {
        [self updateMenuImages:NSMakeSize(16, 16)];
    }
}
```

My apologies for what is almost certainly a dumb mistake on my part, but I'm stumped.

Comment: I usually forget to connect the delegate. In the case of a popup button I would use `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` and the action of the popup button. And it is `menuDidClose:`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My code actually had `menuDidClose:`. I've read so much here and on other sites regarding the NSMenuDelegate methods, I goofed in writing the post. I'm re-looking the delegate connection now that I've had some sleep. ;)

Comment: `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` does get invoked. Unfortunately the code doesn't run until after the menu is displayed and I can find no corresponding DidClose method. I can't connect the File Owner delegate to the popupbutton itself. The parent window is connected. The fact that `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` does get invoked makes me believe the delegate for the popupbutton is correctly connected, just not the menu embedded in the popupbutton?

Comment: `myPopupButton.menu.delegate = self` in initialization

Comment: It is possible to connect the delegate of the menu in the XIB. The menu and the popup button are two separate objects.

Comment: @Willeke I'll have to try that again. When I previously tried to use IB to "draw" the connection to the menu of the popup, it just connected to whatever menu item was under the cursor. Never was able to just connect the menu. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @tbodt Thank you! I'm not sure whose answer came first but this worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menu delegates are not used that often, so Apple hasn't made them too easy to set up in Interface Builder. Instead, do this in `awakeFromNib`:

```
myPopupButton.menu.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I must have tried four different ways to do the same thing but missed the fact that I needed the delegate of the menu of the popup. It seems so obvious in hindsight. :)